# My SQL stop in running server on very week

Tags: mysql, server

I am using GoDaddy server  in last few month MySQL server running is stop self  on the basis of every week.

we need to restart our server or running MySQL we track the event logger but we not found any big issue

how to solve this problem

Comment: What does the error log say ?

Comment: Please post TEXT of last 100 lines of your error log for analysis.  Just after your restart is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Without any logs or detailed information I can only suggest the below:

1. Check mysqld.log to understand what's causing the crash.
2. Check your monitoring tool. Likely for resource consumption and long running queries.
3. Check `/var/log/messages` to understand Out of Memory (OOM) is terminating the mysql service.